# CarPlay entitlement request: How long does it usually take for Apple to respons to a request?

Tags: ios, carplay

Through https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay/ I requested the CarPlay entitlement for my app (a motorcycle navigation app). I did this twice. Once about a year ago, and now a second time about 10 days ago. No response so far.

If it matters: As reason I gave that lots of my users also use the app in their car and more and more motorcycle manufacturers are supporting Carplay on their high end models. My app has about 300k downloads.

Anyone know how long a response usually takes and if I even get a response if they would decline?

Comment: may be one week

Comment: I waited about 8 days for a response from Apple

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'usual' time-frame when it comes to contacting Apple for individual entitlements. Some people have reported 12 months of waiting, some have reported a few weeks – it depends on many factors, all of them undocumented and out of the control of the developers.

Answer (score 2):

Rico from Apple Developer Technical Support says [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82791#330808)

> After applying you must wait for the CarPlay Entitlement usage to be approved. We do not provide timelines for approval.

Comment: Yep. The most annoying is that Apple won't let you know anything if they deny the request. Already entered 5 requests now.